# Aligning custom view in Main Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have created a custom view in .xib using IB. Here is the structure and relative constraints I have created:

[image: structure & constraints]

The layout of custom view is like this:

[image: custom view layout]

I have set the `File's Owner` to `Player.class`. So in `Main.Storyboard` I have added a view and changed it's class name to `Player`. For it's constraints, I have put the `leading` and `trailing` equal to `Superview` with constant 0; so it can stretches the width according to the screen. Now during design time, this is how the Player is appearing in IB:

[image: file view in main.storyboard]

See how it's appearing out of the view. During runtime also the placement of player controls are out of screen.

How to fix this layout to make it appear like in the actual xib layout, making the Slider stretches the width of screen and Player to appear in center?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually my bad. I have to put the following code to make it's alignment according to bounds instead of frame, otherwise it will be offset.

```
view.frame = bounds
```

It then display it perfectly both during IB and at runtime.